# Why C++ hash functions' return type is std::size_t, instead of a platform-independent type?

Tags: c++, hash

As shown [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), `std::hash` template provided in the standard library will return a value of type `std::size_t`. However, the exact type of `std::size_t` is platform-dependent and implementation-dependent, make it impossible to estimate the collision probability.
I cannot see any advantage of returning `std::size_t`, so my problem is, why does not the hash function return a value of fixed type instead?

Comment: From the page you linked: "The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent and are not required to fulfill any other quality criteria except those specified above. Notably, some implementations use trivial (identity) hash functions which map an integer to itself. In other words, these hash functions are designed to work with unordered associative containers, but not as cryptographic hashes, for example. "

Comment: A very common usage pattern for hashes is as an index into an array.  The set of all possible array indices for an implementation can be represented using a `std::size_t`.   This means, even if the array has the maximum allowed size for the implementation, the value returned by the hash function can be used as an index (subject to checking the value is less than the array size).

Comment: If you consider `std::size_t` not to be a "fixed type," then `int` isn't a "fixed type" either because its properties is implementation defined.  And `std::uintN_t` is optional ...

Answer (score 2):

The intended purpose of `std::hash` is for implementation of a hash table, and specifically the unordered associative containers of the standard library. A hash table is an array, and `std::size_t` is an appropriate choice, since it is the type that is guaranteed to be able to represent all indices of any array. While not actually specified by the standard, in practice those standard containers are likely to use `std::size_t` as the size type.

If you need a hash function for inter-system communication, `std::hash` is not a good choice.

Comment: So can I say, for the sake of simplicity, standard committee chose this somehow misleading name?